# Inserting hebrew into NSMutableArrey

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablearray

When I insert Hebrew (LTR) string into NSMutableArrey, the string is distorted somehow.
What do I do?

```
        NSString *peace = @"שלום";
        NSLog(@"peace - %@", peace);

        NSMutableArray *peaceArrey = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
        [peaceArrey addObject:peace];
        NSLog(@"peaceArrey - %@",peaceArrey);
```

And here is the log:

```
        peace - שלום
        peaceArrey - (
            "\U05e9\U05dc\U05d5\U05dd"
        )
```

Comment: everything should be ok, try `NSLog(@"%@", peaceArrey[0]);`

Comment: Oooo :) it worked! So what are these symbols?

Comment: @vikingosegundo maybe you would like to post this as an answer? I'll check it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everything should be ok, try `NSLog(@"%@", peaceArrey[0]);`

the result you are seeing is just the way NSArrays are printed: unicode chars are represented as their codes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mistake the representation that gets logged as the actual value of the object. `NSArray`'s description is in an old-style property list format. Among other things, that means that non-ASCII values in strings are represented as escape sequences. You're seeing the Unicode characters as a series of UTF-16 code units expressed as escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `%@` format specifier `NSLog` calls `description` on the argument to log the string.

In case of a plain string this method just returns the string:

```
NSLog(@"string: %@", @"שלום");
// prints שלום
```

If you, on the other hand, put the string into an array, the `NSArray`'s `description` method is called which, in turn, calls `descriptionWithLocale:indent:`.

This method just creates a property list formatted string. It uses the `NSPropertyListOpenStepFormat` which is ASCII encoded. That's why it has to escape the hebrew unicode characters.